# Do function `getDataAsString` in qml has length limitation?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am writing a small test qml script about drag&drop on windows.

#### test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    id : root
    signal clicked(int x, int y)
    signal filedroped(var url)
    width: 800
    height: 450
    
    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDropped: {
            console.log(drop.getDataAsString('application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileName"'))
            // console.log(drop.urls)
            console.log(drop.text)
        }
    }
}
```

When I drag a folder and drop on the UI, I got:

```
qml: D:\eclipse\CONFIG~1\ORGECL~1.APP\MANAGE~1
qml: file:///D:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.app/.manager
```

Why my filename length is limited in the function `getDataAsString`?

Comment: That's a quirk of Windows. The first filename is a shortened MS-DOS compatible filename, the second is the full length filename. They *probably* represent the same file.

Comment: @MrEricSir Maybe, but when I use traditional qt's `mimeData` object, the method `data` which get mimedata by format returns the full path. PS:where can I use the shortened path? I copied it into the explorer and got an error.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where and how the feature works in Qt, but if you open for example `c:\progra~1` in Explorer it takes you to `"c:\Program Files"`.  The feature dates back to Windows 95 when Microsoft added support for long file names, it's documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982

Comment: @MrEricSir Thanks a lot! In my test I dropped a picture from a rarfile and got a path of temp file. So I got an error in my explorer.